# MSMQ Removed including payloads in a VM without internet and cannot reinstall even with a mounted image

Tags: powershell, msmq, dism

WS2019 VM without internet access, by error introduced in PowerShell removed not only the feature but its payload from server

I really don't know what else to try, any help will be very much appreciated

**Tried**

```
PS C:\\Windows\\system32\> DISM /Online /Get-Features /Format:Table | FINDSTR "^MSMQ-"
MSMQ-Services                                               | Disabled  
MSMQ-Server                                                 | Disabled with Payload Removed
MSMQ-Triggers                                               | Disabled with Payload Removed
MSMQ-ADIntegration                                          | Disabled with Payload Removed
MSMQ-HTTP                                                   | Disabled with Payload Removed
MSMQ-Multicast                                              | Disabled with Payload Removed
MSMQ-DCOMProxy                                              | Disabled with Payload Removed
MSMQ-RoutingServer                                          | Disabled with Payload Removed
```

Extracted info from an uploaded iso WS2019 matching build

```
dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:E:\\sources\\install.wim
```

index for WS2019 Desktop install 2

mounted that image

```
Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:e:\\sources\\install.wim /Index:2 /MountDir:C:\\test\\ /readonly
```

Tried to enable the feature using the mounted image from previous step

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:MSMQ-Server /All /LimitAccess /Source:C:\\test\\windows
```

*E*rror: 0x800f081f*
*The source files could not be found.
Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.*

*The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log*

Tried

```
*PS C:\\Windows\\system32\> Get-WindowsFeature MSMQ*
```

```
Display Name                                            Name                       Install State
------------                                            ----                       -------------
[ ] Message Queuing                                     MSMQ                           Available
    [ ] Message Queuing Services                        MSMQ-Services                  Available
        [ ] Message Queuing Server                      MSMQ-Server                      Removed
        [ ] Directory Service Integration               MSMQ-Directory                   Removed
        [ ] HTTP Support                                MSMQ-HTTP-Support                Removed
        [ ] Message Queuing Triggers                    MSMQ-Triggers                    Removed
        [ ] Multicasting Support                        MSMQ-Multicasting                Removed
        [ ] Routing Service                             MSMQ-Routing                     Removed
    [ ] Message Queuing DCOM Proxy                      MSMQ-DCOM                        Removed
```

```
Add-WindowsFeature MSMQ-Server -Source C:\\test\\Windows
```

```
Add-WindowsFeature : The request to add or remove features on the specified server failed.
Installation of one or more roles, role services, or features failed.
The source files could not be found.
Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.
Error: 0x800f081f
At line:1 char:1

+ Add-WindowsFeature MSMQ-Server -Source C:\\test\\Windows
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (@{Vhd=; Credent...Name=localhost}:PSObject) [Install-WindowsFeature], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DISMAPI_Error__Failed_To_Enable_Updates,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.AddWindowsFeatureCommand

  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Success Restart Needed Exit Code      Feature Result

--------------------------------------------

False   No             Failed         {}
```

Difference between mounted offline and online images

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Dism /Image:C:\test\ /Get-Features /Format:Table | FINDSTR "^MSMQ-"
MSMQ-Services                                                     | Enabled                      
MSMQ-Server                                                       | Enable Pending               
MSMQ-Triggers                                                     | Disabled                     
MSMQ-ADIntegration                                                | Disabled                     
MSMQ-HTTP                                                         | Disabled                     
MSMQ-Multicast                                                    | Disabled                     
MSMQ-DCOMProxy                                                    | Disabled                     
MSMQ-RoutingServer                                                | Disabled                     

PS C:\Windows\system32> DISM /Online /Get-Features /Format:Table | FINDSTR "^MSMQ-"
MSMQ-Services                                               | Disabled                     
MSMQ-Server                                                 | Disabled with Payload Removed
MSMQ-Triggers                                               | Disabled with Payload Removed
MSMQ-ADIntegration                                          | Disabled with Payload Removed
MSMQ-HTTP                                                   | Disabled with Payload Removed
MSMQ-Multicast                                              | Disabled with Payload Removed
MSMQ-DCOMProxy                                              | Disabled with Payload Removed
MSMQ-RoutingServer                                          | Disabled with Payload Removed
```

Comment: You have a virtual machine which is connected to a private network but not to the internet.  You need to transfer the file(s) from the internet to a local machine and then transfer the files to the VM.  How do you connect to the VM?  There are lots of ways to transfer data between machine in a private network.  What methods to you normally use (FTP, SSH, ...).

Comment: @jdweng I can connect to the VM and I have uploaded the iso file and mounted the image, which exact files are you, please, talking about? This is windows and I connect via RDP, my issue is that even that the image is mounted, the version matches the server I cannot find the source files on the source mounted folder the last error is the one I am trying to see if someone have seen before FullyQualifiedErrorId : DISMAPI_Error__Failed_To_Enable_Updates,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.AddWindowsFeatureCommand

Comment: PS uses PSModulePath to locate executables.  You may of install the modules as one user and not all other users.  PSModulePath is an environmental variable and can edit by typing from the start button : Edit Environment variables for your account.  There is both a user and system variable setting.

Comment: Note that ``\`` (a backslash) has _no_ special meaning in PowerShell, so there's never a need to use ``\\`` in file-system paths in order to escape ``\`` chars. 
(PowerShell's [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) - where needed - is `\``, the so-called _backtick_.)

Comment: \\ Those were just typos introduced when copying and pasting here, hard to format, no issues with environmental variables aslo, fixed the issue using a neighbouring server with exact version and build

Answer (score 0):

*** Fixed ***

Used the neighbouring UNC path to `\\SERVER\c$\Windows\WinSxS` as source, which has the same Windows Server Version and build, managed to recover the payload and install the feature

If any further feature will be needed will need to be installed this way

```
Dism /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:MSMQ- /All /Source:\\SERVER\c$\Windows\WinSxS /All /LimitAccess
```

```
DISM /Online /Get-Features /Format:Table | FINDSTR "^MSMQ-"
```

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> DISM /Online /Get-Features /Format:Table | FINDSTR "^MSMQ-"
MSMQ-Services                                             | Enabled                    
MSMQ-Server                                                | Enabled                    
MSMQ-Triggers                                              | Disabled with Payload Removed
MSMQ-ADIntegration                                     | Disabled with Payload Removed
MSMQ-HTTP                                                  | Disabled with Payload Removed
MSMQ-Multicast                                             | Disabled with Payload Removed
MSMQ-DCOMProxy                                       | Disabled with Payload Removed
MSMQ-RoutingServer                                    | Disabled with Payload Removed
```